# Convert Integer to Lat long geo position

Tags: python, gps, coordinates, gis, tracker

I have  python script that tracks teltonika GPS tracker. GPS data are parsed to integer like 
514511623, 2201796 
so devision to 10000000 gives me lat, long. But when tracker passed London coordinates are coming like this 
516631273, 4293416810 so devision give me wrong longitude. Any idea how to convert it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with teltonika GPS tracker. But it seems that the longitude number you are getting has something to do with negative integer. The location is very close to Greenwich where longitude is 0. At the beginning it was 0.22... longitude. Then, it went to negative longitude area. But the GPS receiver only deals with positive integer number. Assuming it uses 32 bit unsigned integer, the max inter is 2**32 = 4294967296 
If you subtract that number from 4293416810

```
4293416810 - 4294967296 = -1550486
-1550486/1e7 = -0.1550486 longitude
```

So the longitude has changed from 0.2201796 to -0.1550486 when you get closer to Greenwich.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue with teltonika devices while working with javascript code. Here is my solution after discussing with teltonika technical team, hope you can convert it to python.

**Note: No need to add a negative sign here as we are subtracting the larger value from the smaller value**

### Fixing lat lon for teltonika devices

```js
// NOTE: lat and lon should be a valid hex of 4 bytes each.
function fixLatLon(num) {
    let maxVal = Math.pow(2, 32-1);
    if (num > maxVal) num = maxVal - num
    return num;
}
```

### Generic Solution

Below is a generic solution to convert `hex` of any length to its appropriate `lat lon`.

**Note this generic solution divides it by 1e7 and gives you the final usable lat,lon**

```js
function getTeltonikaLatLonFromHex(hexString) {
    if (hexString.length % 2 != 0) hexString = "0" + hexString;
    let num = parseInt(hexString, 16);
    let maxVal = Math.pow(2, hexString.length / 2 * 8 - 1);
    if (num > maxVal) num = maxVal - num;
    return num / 1e7;
}
```